# Position in ellipse formula

Tags: math, lua, geometry, love2d

So let's say I got a coordinate grid. I need to know whether or not p0 is located on ellipse starting from p1 ending with p2.

Example with other geometric objects:
-- Rectangle

```
function PositiongOnRectangle(posx, posy, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return (posx >= x1 and posy >= y1 and posx <= x2 and posy <= y2)
end
```

-- circle

```
function PositionOnCircle(posx, posy, x1, y1, radius)
    local distance = math.sqrt((posx - x1)^2 + (posy - y1)^2)
    return (radius >= distance)
end
```

Exmaples above are witten in Lua, however pseudo code will do. I want to do the same but with ellipse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is math definition of oval (starting from p1 ending with p2) - is it ellipse? For ellipse you probably have to define more parameters

Comment: Yes, I meant ellipse.. excuse my English skills.

Comment: Is it inscribed in axis-aligned rectangle, defined by two vertices p1, p2, or these points should lie on the ellipse circumference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ellipse, inscribed in axis-aligned rectangle, defined by two vertices p1, p2:

```
PositionOnEllipse(posx, posy, x1, y1, x2, y2)

///center of ellipse coordinates:
mx = (x1+x2)/2
my = (y1+y2)/2

///ellipse semiaxes:
ax = (x1-x2)/2
ay = (y1-y2)/2 

////due to ellipse equation
 return = (posx-mx)^2/ax^2 + (posy-my)^2/ay^2 <= 1
```

Comment: Ok, now can you please explain what x, y, mx, my means? And how do I know if position is inside the ellipse?

Comment: Also excuse my lack of knowledge of maths/English which made this question even more confusing!

Comment: No problems. Just - oval has no precise mathematical definition, so little clarification was needed.

Comment: Yea, just in Russian "oval" means just that. Well, you live you learn. Thanks again!